# Rails 4 - How to match routes in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi i have admin panel controller and have many controller in admin panel.
I want to match routes usually without namespace i've used

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

I want this in namespace controller my current

router.rb

```
namespace :admin do

get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'

get 'dashboard/index'

##AUTHENTICATION
get 'login/index'
get 'login/logout'
post 'login/attempt_login'
get 'login/attempt_login'

##PAGES
get 'pages/index'
get 'pages/add_new'
get 'pages/edit'
post 'pages/create'
post 'pages/update'
post 'pages/task'
get 'pages/task'

##USERS
get 'users/index'
get 'users/edit'
get 'users/delete'
get 'users/destroy'
get 'users/update'
get 'users/add_new'
post 'users/create'
post 'users/update'
post 'users/task'

#USER GROUPS
get 'user_group/index'
get 'user_group/add_new'
get 'user_group/edit'
post 'user_group/create'
post 'user_group/update'
post 'user_group/task'

#USER GROUPS
get 'access_sections/index'
get 'access_sections/add_new'
post 'access_sections/create'
post 'access_sections/update'
post 'access_sections/task'

end
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply wrap the routes you're declaring in a namespace like so:

```
namespace :login do
   get 'index'
   get 'logout'
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: Thank @mattforni thats a good tip but unfortuantly I was looking for something    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]

Comment: You can put that in a namespace as well.  What exactly are you asking for?  I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Recently i've worked with application which have no namespace and controllers was like

  users_controller.erb
  pages_controller.erb
  some_controller.erb
  another_controller.erb

my routes.erb file was just : 

    root "page#index"
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]

I want this match routes in namespace, right now i have to create routes manually for each controller and actions.. !

Comment: As far as I know that's sort of against RoR best practices.  It's much safer to actually define each of the routes you want as opposed to matching every route so long as it has a single parameter.  I don't recommend what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

For example we have orders which can be cancelled:

Following description in `routes.rb`

```
  resources :orders do
      post :cancel, to: 'orders/cancellations#cancel'
  end
```

Will send request to `app/controllers/orders/cancellations_contoller.rb`

```
module Orders
  class CancellationsController
    def cancel
      @order = Order.find(params[:id]).cancel
    end
  end
end
```

It's useful to refactor controller resourses with many service methods.

Wish it helps